# How to get the cluster's JDBC/ODBC parameters programmatically?

Tags: jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

[Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#get-server-hostname-port-http-path-and-jdbc-url) shows how get the cluster's hostname, port, HTTP path, and JDBC URL parameters from the JDBC/ODBC tab in the UI. See image:

[image: Databricks's JDBC/ODBC Tab]
<sub>(source: [databricks.com](https://docs.databricks.com/_images/jdbc-odbc-tab-aws.png))</sub>

Is there a way to get the same information programmatically? I mean using the Databricks API or Databricks CLI. I am particularly interested in the `HTTP path` which contains the **Workspace Id**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Get operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/api/sql-endpoints#get) of the SQL Analytics REST API (maybe together with `List`) - it returns the JDBC connection string as a part of response (`jdbc_url` field):

```
{
  "id": "123456790abcdef",
  "name": "My SQL endpoint",
  "cluster_size": "Medium",
  "min_num_clusters": 1,
  "max_num_clusters": 10,
  "auto_stop_mins": 30,
  "num_clusters": 5,
  "num_active_sessions": 30,
  "state": "RUNNING",
  "creator_name": "user@example.com",
  "jdbc_url":"jdbc:spark://<databricks-instance>:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=/sql/protocolv1/o/0123456790abcdef;",
  "odbc_params": {
    "host": "<databricks-instance>",
    "path": "/sql/protocolv1/o/0/123456790abcdef",
    "protocol": "https",
    "port": 443
  }
}
```

HTTP Path is also there, as `path` part of the `odbc_params` object.

Comment: Awesome, looks like this is what I am after. However, I am getting: `{"error_code":"FEATURE_DISABLED","message":"SQL Gateway is not supported for Org XXXX}` Why listing endpoints is in preview?

Comment: interesting... Do you have SQL Analytics enabled for this workspace? I just checked my own Azure workspace, and API works just fine

Comment: I think this is only applicable to sql endpoints not clusters. Kombajn zbożowy answer is more correct when it comes to Azure databricks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to go to Databricks console

1. Click compute icon Compute in the sidebar.
2. Choose a cluster to connect to.
3. Navigate to Advanced Options.
4. Click on the JDBC/ODBC tab.
5. Copy the connection details.

More details [here](https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#get-connection-details-for-a-cluster)

Comment: Question was about programmatic access to that data :-)

Comment: Above comment is true, this didn't answer the question asked, but I was still glad to find it here; easier/more direct path to achieve something I only need to do once.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available directly from Databricks API, but this is the template for cluster JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:spark://<db-hostname>:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/<workspace-id>/<cluster-id>;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=<personal-access-token>
```

- `db-hostname` is your hostname of your instance URL
- `workspace-id` is the long numeric in your hostname (https://adb-**1234512345123456**.2.azuredatabricks.net/). It is available as `workspaceId` in output of `az databricks workspace list` or you can parse it from hostname
- `cluster-id` the cluster you want the connection string for
- `personal-access-token` is the token used for authentication

So all of above you already have or can get programmatically and substitute into template. It's a bit cumbersome, but that's the best we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution offered by @Kombajn zbożowy

I used the following to get the cluster Id and workspace Id to build the Http Path dynamically.

```
cluster_id = spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterId")

workspace_id =spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterOwnerOrgId")

http_path = f"sql/protocolv1/o/{workspace_id}/{cluster_id}"
```